# Domino 12 give error xpages WARNING: Xsp Initialization error - Could not load class or methods

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I installed domino 12 after its work but give errors on console about xpages WARNING: Xsp Initialization error - Could not load class or methods

[image]

Comment: Did you deselect Inotes during the install? I think that Inotes is needed. Try a reinstall with all options selected.

Comment: Also if you didn't do a reboot before and did the install using run as administrator. Sometimes some java files are locked.

Comment: many many thanks Fredrik,Per Henrik. I reinstalled after restart everythink is ok.